# Reversing the linked list changes original linked list

Tags: python, linked-list

I am trying to reverse a linked list and I've observed that the original head is also being changed. 
Below is the code I'm using:

```
def reverseRecursive(head):

    if head == None:
        return head
    if head.next == None:
        return head

    newHead = reverseRecursive(head.next)

    tail = head.next
    tail.next =head
    head.next = None

    return newHead

#Original list: (1 --> 2 --> 3 --> 4 --> 5 --> None)

printLL(reverseRecursive(head))           #Output: 5 --> 4 --> 3 --> 2 --> 1 --> None
printLL (head)                            #Output: 1 --> None
```

I've rectified this by reversing a deep copy of the linked list but the problem I'm facing is that in
another problem where I passed the original head as an argument and manipulated it, the original head did not move from its place. See code below:

```
def printLL(head):
    while head is not None:
        print(str(head.data) + " --> ", end="")
        head = head.next
    print("None")

#call
head = takeInput()
printLL(head)            #Output:1 --> 2 --> 3 --> 4 --> 5 --> None
printLL(head)            #Output:1 --> 2 --> 3 --> 4 --> 5 --> None
```

I know python utilizes 'call by assignment' but why in the first code it seems like the head is being passed by reference and in the second being passed by value?

Answer (score 0):

call the function `reverseRecursive` and update the `head` to be `head=reverseRecursive(head);` then print the list (after the update).

Comment: Does not answer my question.